# Replace every nth comma in a .htb file

Tags: python, mysql, replace

My goal is to import a .htb file to a mysql table. But before i can do that i need to edit the file and replace every 96th comma with a \n. The reason for that is the mysql tabe has 96 columns und for the import i need to insert the \n as a delimiter for the lines. The original file contains values which are comma separated:

```
68.000000000000,89.000000000000,115.000000000000,0.500000000000,
```

I have tried using the following code but it replaces all the commas with a \n:

```
with open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Iveco_Cursor_DMC_Aufbereitet.htb", "r") as infile, \
     open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Final.htb", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    data = data.replace(','[:96], '\n')
    outfile.write(data)
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I believe this would give you the desired result

```py
with open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Iveco_Cursor_DMC_Aufbereitet.htb", "r") as infile, \
    open("C:/Users/l-reh/Desktop/HTB_neu/Final.htb", "w", encoding="utf8") as outfile:
    data = infile.read()
    newData = ''
    n = 0
    for element in data:
        if element == ',':
            n += 1
            if n == 96:
                newData += '\n'
                n = 0
            else:
                newData += element
        else:
            newData += element
    outfile.write(newData)
```